# How to make it say a specific thing if it can't find a number (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm working on a small discord bot that will ask for an input number and then chose a random number from 0 to the number that was inputted by the user. Sometimes a user enters in a random digit that isn't a number and the bot will respond with "You Rolled a NaN". Is there a way to make it so I can have it say "Please Enter a number" if it can't find a number?

here's my code

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

function getRandomInt(max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

const prefix = 'roll';

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('your bot name is online!');
    client.user.setActivity("Type 'Role Help'", {type: 3}); 
});

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === ''){
       message.channel.send("What's the **Max** role number you want?");
       message.channel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id == message.author.id,
        {max: 1, time: 10000}).then(collected => {
            if(collected.first().content == 'stop'){
                message.channel.send('*Roll has been stopped.*');
            };
            console.log('collected :' + collected.first().content);
            var n = (getRandomInt(collected.first().content));
            message.channel.send("You Rolled a " + (n + 1));
            }).catch(() => {
                message.channel.send("*Roll has been cancelled.*");
     
            })} else if(command === 'Help' || 'help'){

                message.channel.send("**How to use Role Bot**");
                message.channel.send("*1. Type Role to begin*");
                message.channel.send("*2. Input a number or type stop to end the roll.*");
                message.channel.send("**Have Fun!**");
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) to check if the user's input is a number or not.

---

```js
console.log(`"test" is ${isNaN("test") ? "not a number" : "a number"}!`);
console.log(`12 is ${isNaN(12) ? "not a number" : "a number"}!`);
```

---

```js
if (isNaN(collected.first().content)) return message.channel.send("Please provide a valid number!")
```